# I need to print without comma in last position

Tags: python

```
n = int(input("Enter a number :-"))
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(i*n, end = ",")
```

When I tried this program, in output I have got a comma in the last position. But I don't want this comma. How can I remove the comma?
I just code it for a **multiplication table**.

Output:
8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64,72,80,

Comment: `print(','.join(str(x * n) for x in range(1, 11)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the index before printing

```
n = int(input("Enter a number :-"))
for i in range(1, 11):
    end = "," if i < 10 else ""
    print(i*n, end = end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python lets you do this easily with `join`:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(','.join(str(i*n) for i in range(1, n)))  # surely, range(1, n) not range(1, 11)
```

For more complex situations, a common solution is to *prefix* each item except the first.

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
sep = ""
for i in range(1, n):  # same fix here
    print("%s%i" % (sep, i*n), end = "")
    sep = ","   # add a delimiter on each subsequent iteration
```

Answer (score 1):

Produce a series which you pass into `print` all at once with a custom separator, instead of requiring to figure out the correct end-of-line in separate `print` calls:

```
print(*(i*n for i in range(1, 11)), sep=',')
```

This `*` unpacks the generator `(i*n for i in range(1, 11))` as arguments to `print`, in essence being equivalent to:

```
print(8, 16, 24, ..., sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is using **Join function**

**using Using generator expression:**

```
def gen_num(n,count):
    for i in range(1, count):
        yield str(i*n)

print(",".join(list(gen_num(8,11))))
```

**using list comprehension**

```
n = 8
print(",".join([str(x*n) for x in range(1,11)]))
```

Result: `8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64,72,80`

Comment: FWIW, the `[]` are superfluous. You can use a *generator expression* instead of a list comprehension here.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for suggestion: I have updated generator expression also in it.

Comment: Uhm, no, that's an even more complex *generator function*. All I said was `print(",".join(str(x*n) for x in range(1,11)))` is sufficient…